Two dogs in Stardew Valley bug
I was playing Stardew Valley on mobile (iPad Gen 9) and got the cutscene where you can choose a pet. I chose a German shepherd and named it Ollie, and then went about my day. The next day I got the cutscene again, chose the same dog, and named it the same thing. I went to sleep in-game, expecting it to disappear but it was still there and has been there ever since. The duplicate doesn't seem to require water, but I can pet it still and it shows the heart emoji over the dog like normal. I have not downloaded any mods or packages that may cause this glitch or anything like this. I have some questions about this:

Why did the glitch happen?
Any pros/cons?
Could I get rid of the second dog?


Which mobile? Maybe it's important

I was playing on Ipad gen 9

This seems to be a very popular bug (enough for Screenrant to write an article about it). Couldn't find any cons. People definitely like being able to have two pets (though 1.6 added being able to buy a second pet)
